# How do I read from a file located inside a Chrome extension bundle?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Every page on the internet seems to suggest a different option for this, and who knows what's deprecated and what isn't. What's the "correct" way to read a file from within the extension bundle? I don't want to inline the data into the script files themselves, both because it's awful practice and because it consumes an unnecessary amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch is the newest and easiest. It works in all cases except getting a list of the packaged files at runtime, which requires [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).

```
fetch("manifest.json").then(function(response) {
 return(response.json())
}).then(function(manifest) {
 console.log(manifest)
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch